# brasero: "name.ext" is not suitable for audio or video media

Tags: audio, slackware, burning, brasero

I try to create an Audio CD using brasero 3.12.3-x86_64-1salix15 on a Slackware 15.0 based system.
slapt-get added the following packages to meet all dependencies:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  graphene gstreamer gst-plugins-base libburn libisofs brasero
```

The exact versions of the packages:

```
1/6 Get http://slackware.uk/salix/x86_64/slackware-15.0/ graphene 1.10.6-x86_64-1 [104.0kB]...Done
2/6 Get http://slackware.uk/salix/x86_64/slackware-15.0/ gstreamer 1.18.5-x86_64-1 [1.7MB]...Done
3/6 Get http://slackware.uk/salix/x86_64/slackware-15.0/ gst-plugins-base 1.18.5-x86_64-1 [2.2MB]...Done
4/6 Get http://slackware.uk/salix/x86_64/slackware-15.0/ libburn 1.5.4-x86_64-2 [288.0kB]...Done
5/6 Get http://slackware.uk/salix/x86_64/15.0/ libisofs 1.5.4-x86_64-1gv [259.0kB]...Done
6/6 Get http://slackware.uk/salix/x86_64/extra-15.0/ brasero 3.12.3-x86_64-1salix15.0 [2.4MB]...Done
```

Starting brasero I get no errors in the terminal that started it:

```
rava@rava1:/$ brasero
```

When I click the "Audio project / Create a traditional audio CD" icon nothing happens in the terminal, but when I then click on the "+" icon ("Add files to the project") and the Open File Window opens, the starting terminal tells me this

```
(brasero:8385): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 20:31:29.706: attempting to add an interface (EggTreeMultiDragSource) to class (GtkFileSystemModel) after class_init
```

The same error is repeated every time I go around in my filesystem (only the time stamp of the error changes)

And when I select any .wav or .mp3 that should be suitable, I always get this error:

```
"name.ext" could not be opened.
"name.ext" is not suitable for audio or video media.
```

**I tested several files that should be suitable, but all create the above error.** Since the file I want to burn as Audio CD is sampled as 48000 Hz I used lame to convert that into a 44100 Hz highest quality mp3 because when in audacity-linux-3.2.1-x86_64 I set the sample rate to 44100 Hz but the exported .wav file still had 48000 Hz.

```
lame --resample 44100 --preset extreme lamesh_11100_1.wav
```

This is what ffprobe reports on that mp3 that I converted via lame mp3 with the above parameters:

```
$ ffprobe -hide_banner lamesh_11100_1.mp3
Input #0, mp3, from 'lamesh_11100_1.mp3':
  Duration: 01:03:39.49, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 216 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 216 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.100
    Side data:
      replaygain: track gain - 0.500000, track peak - unknown, album gain - unknown, album peak - unknown,
```

but still, brasero keeps insisting on

```
"lamesh_11100_1.mp3" could not be opened.
"lamesh_11100_1.mp3" is not suitable for audio or video media.
```

Any ideas why that might be? Is some dependency missing or not working correct and brasero not tells me about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the warnings you get and the behaviour you see sound like bugs (but they don't seem to be related, just separate issues).

Couple of notes:

> I used lame to convert that into a 44100 Hz highest quality mp3

Why? that makes no sense. Converting to MP3 is lossy, even at high qualities, and while I haven't tried LAME in a decade, I remember it honestly not being the best encoder.

Brasero *should* be (and in the past, has been) able to resample (that's the name for the process of changing sampling rates without changing the audio). Either way, taking a detour through the (technically, by 2023) obsolete MP3 format is a bad idea. You could resample into a WAV just as well. You have `ffmpeg` installed, so that would be super easy:

```
ffmpeg -i original_file_at_48_kHz.wav -ar 44100 out_at_44_1_kHz.wav
```

> because when in audacity-linux-3.2.1-x86_64 I set the sample rate to 44100 Hz but the exported .wav file still had 48000 Hz.

lol, your converter then resampled again :)

Anyway, none of this conversion should be necessary, and assuming you don't want to modify Brasero's source code to fix any bugs, maybe, just, don't use Brasero.

I don't know what is available on Slackware, but other distros ship usually both `xfburn` (*very* slim, but should do what you need) and `k3b`. So, pick one of these and try them.

Comment: I try xfburn. I saw brasero talked about on several sites and thought I try it out, seems that was the wrong choice.

Comment: I think it might be just the slackware build that has these problems

Comment: Slackware build should have no such error. I went with xfburn instead, but that also gave a similar error; I then added a dependency slapt-get did not mention and after that it works, but I had to use the `[…] -ar 44100 out_at_44_1_kHz.wav` conversion first. So much thanks for that one liner.